# RestTemplate and serialization of List of Objects

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I'm using RestTemplate from Spring to query a search service. And I have some difficulties to have a correct serialization. 
If I use this method, the restTemplate returns a List.
I don't understand how to pass the parameterized type

```
UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromUri(uri+ "/search");
builder = builder.queryParam("category", category);
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(createHeaders(user, pwd));
ResponseEntity<List> search = searchTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toString(), HttpMethod.GET, request, List.class);
return search.getBody();
```

PS : I already tried GeoPriceStats[].class instead of List.class

any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `ParameterizedTypeReference`.

```
ResponseEntity<List<GeoPriceStats>> search = 
    searchTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toString(),
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            request,
                            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<GeoPriceStats>>() {});
```